# How can I get current user in ModelForm init()?

Tags: python, django

I want to show different contents for each user with different  privilege, I'm trying to get current user from `init()` function in ModelForm class, but failed

the code below is my current init() in ModelForm

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

but self.user only works after the form has been sent, like in  `is_valid()` function or in `clean_data()` function

I always get "None" value of `self.user` in `init()`
Should I keep trying to get current user in ModelForm `init()`,
or maybe there is a better way to implement that funtionality?

Comment: You have to pass the user to the form obviously - `kwargs.pop('user',None)` will not automagically insert `user` in kwargs if it's not been passed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to send this Data from View. For example, in a [Generic Class Based Edit View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) you can use [get_form_kwargs()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs):

```
class YourView(FormView):
   form_class = YourForm
   ...

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(YourView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

In other scenario, initiate form with passing known argument `user`:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = YourForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = MyForm(user=request.user) // where you are calling the form in the view
```

and the constructor will look like:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
         super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a new file in your project folder and named middleware.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

try:
    from threading import local
except ImportError:
    from django.utils._threading_local import local

_thread_locals = local()

def get_current_request():
    """ returns the request object for this thread """
    return getattr(_thread_locals, "request", None)

def get_current_user():
    """ returns the current user, if exist, otherwise returns None """
    request = get_current_request()
    if request:
        return getattr(request, "user", None)

class ThreadLocalMiddleware(object):
    """ Simple middleware that adds the request object in thread local stor    age."""

    def process_request(self, request):
        _thread_locals.request = request

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if hasattr(_thread_locals, 'request'):
    del _thread_locals.request
        return response
```

Then, config your setting file:

**settings.py:**

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.middleware.ThreadLocalMiddleware',
]

Use the function get_current_user() anywhere you want to get curent user.
**Example**
**models.py:**

```
from YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.middleware import get_current_user

...

Class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def some_method(self):
        current_user = get_current_user()
        ....
```

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please take (at least) the parts that are required for a minimal working opy from the link and add it to your answer in case the link might become broken in the future.

Comment: You should give proper attribution (at least the link to where you got this antipattern recipe from) - but it's really an antipattern, Django has been specifically designed to properly decouple the domain from the request/response cycle so your domain code doesn't NEED a request to work (which is the RightThing(tm) to do).